# Position flex div dynamically below another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position several buttons within a div (button-menu) to be below another div (container) dynamically depending on the screen size. Right now if the screen-size is below 700px, I have an image (character_image) that moves below container and aligns on the right side.

I need my button-menu buttons to always be below container, but to not overlap with or be positioned below character_image when the screen is smaller than 700px.

Here's what I'm trying to do (Photoshopped).

[image]

[image]

What's the best way to do this? I know normally I could use flex-box to position button-menu next to character_image, but since that image is already positioned dynamically with media query, I don't know how to position button-menu where it needs to be.

Here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

I actually can't even figure out how to get button-menu below the other div at all. I know normally it would wrap under the other div automatically if it's too wide, but container doesn't have a set width (Nor do I want it to) and fills up the blank space, so how do I force button-menu to position below container instead of next to it?

Do I enter a new line in the HTML manually or is there some really obvious way to do this that I'm not realizing?

Here's my CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Benne', serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#question {
    font-size: 1.5rem; /* fallback */
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: .4em;
    background: ghostwhite;
}

.container:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0.813em solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: -0.406em;
    margin-right: -0.812em;
}

.btn-grid {
    /*display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    height: 20%;*/
    display: flex;
    height: 20%;
}

.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: black;/*Button Color*/
    color: white;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #627295;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
}
.btn:active {/*on Click*/
    -ms-transform: translateY(4px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px);/*Move down*/
    border-bottom: none;/*disappears*/
}

.start-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: flex; /* Use flexbox */
    flex-direction: row; /* Flex horizontally (this is default flex-direction)*/
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: 5vw auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#chat_bubble {
    width: 70vw; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport width */
    min-height: 70vh; /* Make chat bubble 70% of viewport height at minimum*/
}

#character_image  {
    float: none; /* undo float */
    flex-shrink: 1; /* let character image shrink */
    height: 70vh; /* Make character_image 70% of viewport height */
}

#character_image img {
    height: 100%;
}

#char_1 {
    display: inline-block;
}

#char_2 {
    display: none;
}

#button_menu {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

@media(max-width:700px) {
    #main {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #chat_bubble {
        width: 90vw;
    }
    #character_image {
        height: 30vh;
    }
    #char_1 {
        display: none;
    }
    #char_2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .container:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        top: unset;
        right: unset;
        left: 50%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 0.813em solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        margin-left: -0.406em;
        margin-bottom: -0.812em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css-grid. Set #main display to grid. Setup grid areas as such

```
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'chat_bubble character_image'
        'button_menu button_menu';
}
#character_image {
    grid-area: character_image;
}
#chat_bubble {
    grid-area: chat_bubble;
}
#button_menu {
    grid-area: button_menu;
}
```

Then in your media query change the layout of your grid

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    #main {
        grid-template-areas:
            'chat_bubble chat_bubble'
            'button_menu character_image';
    }
}
```

You will most likely need to play with other styles to make it flow just how you want, but this way you get the layout you wanted.
Checkout [Fireship's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=705XCEruZFs) for more detail or ask me for more explanations.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm so bad with CSS it took me a week just to get everything to work properly with the flex-box. I tried your code but there's absolutely no way I'm going to be able to adjust the settings or fix it from here, because it literally consumed about 100+ hours of my last week adjusting the settings. 

The part that really complicates things is container and character_image grow and shrink differently depending on the screen size. Because of that, someone recommended I use flex instead of grid which is that I've been trying to implement for the last week.

Comment: Do you think grid is necessary to do this? Because if so it's going to set me back another week or so, and I'll probably have to pay people to help me fix it because I'm really bad at this stuff.

Comment: Do you think it would work if I hid character_image when the screen is under 700px and then had another image that was part of the button-menu flexbox to avoid the issues with the button-menu not aligning with character_image? Is there anyway that wouldn't involve having to relearn and rewrite everything?

Comment: I think css-grid is the easiest way out. The dynamic image size can also be achieved with grid. The trick with two images will also definetly work with switching display: none | block;. This would be also the easiest option for you, I think. If you want I can make it with css-grid and explain it shortly to you later.

Comment: If you don't mind I would really appreciate it, it would really help me out if it's not going to take you a long time. I've been trying to teach myself CSS to become more competent with it, but it's not going very well. Thank you.

Comment: So I've made something like this https://svelte.dev/repl/d62edf2f9bd6463a8cef19484270aedd?version=3.38.3 
I used Svelte which just only makes it possible to write in a single file css,js and html just cuz i really dislike code pen. You can write to me at maciej.pietrek@gmail.com for more explanations. Your styles got a little broken, but that I think you can figure out. Also I don't know how you would exactly the layout to look.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I can figure it out from here but I'll e-mail you if not. I really, really appreciate that.